# boton dentro de mi carrito

Tags: javascript

estoy a punto de entregar mi sitio web para que sea corregido, y tengo que añadir un boton, el cual dentro de mi carrito, debera sumar el producto respectivo. Les dejo el codigo a ver si alguien me puede dar una mano, estoy programando hace mucho, estoy quemado y no se me ocurre.

Primero de todo creo las cards y las muestro en la pagina:

```
const traigoJson = async()=> {
  const respuesta = await fetch ('../stock.json')
  const data = await respuesta.json()

  let contenedor = document.getElementById("container")

  data.forEach((producto, indice) => {

  let card = document.createElement("div")

  card.classList.add("col-xl-3", "col-lg-3", "col-md-6", "col-sm-6", "hide", `${producto.deporte}`, "products")
  card.innerHTML = `<div class="glasses_box">
      <figure><img src="${producto.imagen}" alt="esta es una foto de ${producto.nombre}"/></figure>
      <h3><span class="blu">$</span>${producto.precio}</h3>
      <p class="product-name">${producto.nombre}</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary boton-comprar" id="asd" onClick = "agregarAlCarrito (${indice})">COMPRAR</button>
   </div>`

  contenedor.appendChild(card)
  
  producto.card = card;
})
}
traigoJson()
```

Despues de esto, creo un array vacio que sera mi carrito y agrego los productos correspondientes.

```
let cart = [];
let modalCarrito = document.getElementById("cart")
let contadorCarrito = 0;


const agregarAlCarrito = async(indice)=>  {
  const respuesta = await fetch ('../stock.json')
  const data = await respuesta.json()

    const indiceEncontradoCarrito = cart.findIndex((elemento) => {
        return elemento.id === data[indice].id
    })
    if (indiceEncontradoCarrito === -1) {
        const productoAgregar = data[indice]
        productoAgregar.cantidad = 1
        cart.push(productoAgregar)
        dibujarCarrito()
    }else {
        cart[indiceEncontradoCarrito].cantidad += 1
        dibujarCarrito()
    }
};
```

Por ultimo ""dibujo"" mi carrito, lo muestro en un canvas de bootstrap.

```
const dibujarCarrito = () => {
    modalCarrito.className = "cart";
    modalCarrito.innerHTML = ""     
    if(cart.length > 0) {
        cart.forEach((producto, indice) => {
            const carritoContainer = document.createElement("div");
            carritoContainer.className = "producto-carrito"
            carritoContainer.innerHTML = `
            <img class = "car-img" src="${producto.imagen}"/>
            <div class="product-details>
                ${producto.nombre}
            </div>
            <div class="product-details"> Cantidad: ${producto.cantidad}</div>
            <div class="product-details"> Precio: $ ${producto.precio}</div>
            <div class="product-details"> Subtotal: $ ${
                producto.precio * producto.cantidad
            }</div>
            <button class="btn btn-dark" id="remove-product" onClick="removeProduct(${indice})">Eliminar producto</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onClick = "agregarAlCarrito (${indice})">Add product.</button>
            `;
            modalCarrito.appendChild(carritoContainer);

        })
        
        let initialTotal = 0;
        const grandTotal = cart.reduce((previousValue, currentItem) => previousValue + (currentItem.precio * currentItem.cantidad),
        initialTotal);

        const totalContainer = document.createElement("div")
        totalContainer.className = "total-carrito";
        totalContainer.innerHTML = `<div class = "total"> TOTAL $ ${grandTotal} </div>
        <button class = "btn btn-dark finalizar" id="finalizar" onClick = "finalizarCompra()"><a href="../paginas/simulacion-compra.html">FINALIZAR COMPRA</a></button>`
        modalCarrito.appendChild(totalContainer)

        localStorage.setItem("productos", JSON.stringify(cart)) 
        
    } else {
        modalCarrito.classList.remove("cart")
    }         
}
```

Basicamente lo que necesito y quiero hacer son botones de "comprar" dentro del carrito, que agregue en 1 el producto correspondiente al boton. En la funcion dibujarCarrito probe agregando el boton, pero solo funciona si los productos son seleccionados en orden.